# Translate VS inline assembler to GCC inline assembler

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-16, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler

I find this C code with inline assembler code:

```
ReadFromCMOS (unsigned char array [])
{
   unsigned char tvalue, index;

   for(index = 0; index < 128; index++)
   {
      _asm
      {
         cli             /* Disable interrupts*/
         mov al, index   /* Move index address*/
         /* since the 0x80 bit of al is not set, NMI is active */
         out 0x70,al     /* Copy address to CMOS register*/
         /* some kind of real delay here is probably best */
         in al,0x71      /* Fetch 1 byte to al*/
         sti             /* Enable interrupts*/
         mov tvalue,al
       }

       array[index] = tvalue;
   }
}

WriteTOCMOS(unsigned char array[])
{
   unsigned char index;

   for(index = 0; index < 128; index++)
   {
      unsigned char tvalue = array[index];
      _asm
      {
         cli             /* Clear interrupts*/
         mov al,index    /* move index address*/
         out 0x70,al     /* copy address to CMOS register*/
         /* some kind of real delay here is probably best */
         mov al,tvalue   /* move value to al*/
         out 0x71,al     /* write 1 byte to CMOS*/
         sti             /* Enable interrupts*/
      }
   }
}
```

I tried to translate to GNU inline assembler, but I failed, mostly because GNU inline asm is messy, uses the archaic AT&T syntax and is difficult to use.

Code that gives me error:

```
void read_cmos(unsigned char array[])
{
    unsigned char tvalue, index;
    for (index = 0; index < 128; ++index)
    {
        /* read from CMOS */
        asm ("cli; outb %1, $0x70; inb $0x71, %0; sti" : "=a"(tvalue) : "a"(index));
    }
    array[index] = tvalue;
}
```

Comment: We don't know the context but usually you should have (or make) separate functions or macros for `cli`, `sti` and `out` so you don't need to use inline assembly all over the place.

Comment: I'm actually making a bootloader. I solved my problem thanks to @fuz but doesn't worked, it produces a stack overflow maybe?.

Comment: @konniskatt Where lies your confusion?  Perhaps I can help clear it up.

Comment: Assuming a relatively simple ABI for passing arguments, etc., I think you'd be a lot better off simply writing these function in assembly! The *hard* part is already provided, and the rest is just book keeping. Combine with the answer by @fuz, compile C -> assembler, then take the time to examine, validate, and possibly optimize the results.

Comment: BTW - include your function return type (even if it's `void`) - this will matter for return value conventions etc., as part of the ABI.

Comment: Well, this is the only function in all the file (rtc.h) in all the code there is nothing but the function read_cmos

Comment: There's nothing weird before `#include "kernel/rtc.h"`

Comment: Here's the complete project: https://gitlab.com/konniskatt/dosclone/ Not a very creative name btw

Comment: @konniskatt The problem is that you compile with `-std=c99` where `asm` is not recognised as a keyword.  Change all mentions of `asm` to `__asm__` to fix this or use `-std=gnu99` instead.  This would have been easier to find if you (a) posted all errors you got and (b) the exact sequence of commands you typed to compile the code.  Took me a while to find this one.

Comment: I just found that as well fuz, you beat me to typing it up lol. What would have helped is having this warnign given to us `warning: implicit declaration of function 'asm' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` . That would have been a tell tale sign that he was using `-std` that wasn't compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
/* read from CMOS */
asm ("cli; outb %1, $0x70; inb $0x71, %0; sti" : "=a"(tvalue) : "a"(index));

/* write to CMOS */
unsigned char i = index;
asm volatile ("cli; outb %0, $0x70; movb %1, %%al; outb %%al, $0x71; sti" : "+a"(i) : "rm"(tvalue));
```

Note that using an extra variable for `tvalue` is optional.  You could also specify

```
"+a"(array[index])
```

or

```
"a"(array[index])
```

directly.  What matters is that the expression you pass has a byte-sized type so gcc picks `al` instead of `eax`.

Assigning `index` to `i` is needed to allow `al` to be clobbered without changing the value of `index`. This code should just work.  Alternatively, the second set of instructions can also be split up into two:

```
asm volatile ("cli; outb %0, $0x70" :: "a"(index));
asm volatile ("outb %0, %0x71" :: "a"(tvalue));
```

This avoids the need for an extra variable and gives greater flexibility to the compiler when chosing registers.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this code assumes that interrupts were on to begin with as it always enables them whether they were previously enabled or not.

Comment: kernel/rtc.h:7:50: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
   asm ("cli; outb %1, $0x70; inb $0x71, %0; sti" : "=a"(tvalue) : "a"(index));

Comment: @konniskatt Please append your code to the question.  This works on my machine, so I'm not entirely sure what is wrong with it.  Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I use i686-elf-gcc

Comment: @konniskatt Which version?  Please post the code you tried to compile or a [mcve] that reproduces the issue so I can understand what went wrong.

Comment: Version 4.9.1 Here's the code that produces the error: https://pastebin.com/z6vkfmtJ

Comment: @konniskatt Please add this code to your question by clicking “edit” and pasting it in.  I do not consider external resources when answering Stack Overflow questions as each question must be self-contained.

Comment: @konniskatt I've tried compiling your code with all gcc versions I have access to, including versions of gcc 4.8 and gcc 4.9 and I cannot reproduce your error.  Are you sure there are no macros or other weird things involved in this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the (ancient) GCC-inline-assembly HOWTO (geared towards i686 Linux, so probably right on for your use), check the argument passing/constraints carefully (they allow GCC to arrange calling code right, by e.g. placing the inputs/outputs in the registers used). The GCC documentation on inline assembly is also relevant, but somewhat opaque in my memory, much more detailed, covering many more architectures in detail (but presumably more up to date).

(Sorry, can't place links on my phone. A quick search should give them as first hits.)